# The images of all functions in a family contain a disk of fixed radius.

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been trying to tackle this question and I feel like I've got the right idea, but I can't quite finish it off.

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the set of analytic functions $f$ on $\mathbb{D}$ such that $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=1$, and $|f(z)|\le 100$ on $\mathbb{D}$. Show that there exists $r>0$ such that $B(0, r)\subseteq f(\mathbb{D})$ for all $f\in\mathscr{F}$.

Here's what I have so far:

By Montel's Theorem, $|f(z)|\le 100$ implies that $\mathscr{F}$ is a normal family of functions. $\mathscr{F}$ is also closed, hence compact, so any sequence in $\mathscr{F}$ contains a subsequence that converges (in $\mathscr{H}(\mathbb{D})$) to a function in $\mathscr{F}$.

Suppose that the conclusion is false; for each $n$, choose $f_n\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $f_n$ omits a value with modulus less than $\frac{1}{n}$. Let $f_n\to f\in\mathscr{F}$.

Now, how do I get to the contradiction that $f$ cannot be in $\mathscr{F}$?

I've tried saying that $f$ maps a neighborhood of $0$ to a neighborhood of $0$ that contains a disk of some radius, since $f'(0)\not=0$. For large enough $n$, the image of the same neighborhood under $f_n$ omits values in that disk, and as $n$ grows the omitted values do not tend to the boundary. This argument seems intuitively right, but I don't think it's anywhere near rigorous enough for a real proof. Any hints or help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a compactness argument, I'd rather do something  *constructive*. Write $f(z)=z+z^2g(z)$ where $g$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb D$. Since $|z^2g(z)|\le 101$ in  $\mathbb D$, it follows that $|g(z)|\le 101$ (apply the maximum principle to $|g(z)|\le 101/|z|^2$ on the circle $|z|=r$ and let $r\to 1$).

Given any $w$ with $|w|<1/404$, apply Rouche's theorem to $(z-w)+z^2 g(z)$ on the disk $B=\{z:|z|<1/202\}$. On the boundary of the disk, $|z-w|>\frac{1}{404}$ and $|z^2g(z)| \le \frac{1}{202^2}\cdot 101 = \frac{1}{404}$. Since the function $z-w$ has a zero in $B$, so does the sum $z-w+z^2 g(z)$, which is $f(z)-w$.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but I don't think that if $|g(z)|<|f(z)|$ along a Jordan curve then $f+g$ attains every value $f$ does on its interior. E.g. $\frac{1}{2}<|z|$ along $\partial\mathbb{D}$ but $z+\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't attain $-\frac{3}{4}$ in $\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: @JonathanY. Thanks, I fixed the (dumb) mistake I made there. So it's $1/404$, a nice number...

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It's nifty and not at all something I would have thought of. I'd still like to see a solution along the lines of what I was working on, though.

Comment: @acoustician Let $z_n\to 0$ be values omitted by $f_n$ in your proof. Then $f_n-z_n\to f$. The [Hurwitz Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) tells you that for sufficiently large $n$, the function $f_n-z_n$ has a zero. Contradiction.

Comment: @user90090 I thought of that, but the functions $f_n-z_n$ are not in $\mathscr{F}$.

Comment: @acoustician That does not matter for the purpose of getting a contradiction. The normality of the class was already used to produce a convergent sequence; after that the class is not needed.