# Holomorphic functions from disk to disk with fixed derivative at origin

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb D$ be the unit disk on $\mathbb C$, and $r\mathbb D$ be the disk of radius $r$ centered at the origin. (When $r=\infty$, $r\mathbb D$ means $\mathbb C$. )

Fix $\infty\geq r\geq a\geq0$, and consider the family of functions:

$$ \mathscr S(a,r)=\{f:\mathbb D\to r\mathbb D \;\mathrm{ holomorphic}, \left|f'(0)\right|=a\}$$

and let

$$ D(a,r)=\bigcap_{f\in \mathscr S(a,r)} f(\mathbb D)$$

By rotational symmetry and connectedness, $D(a,r)$ is a closed disk $\overline B(0,d)$ or an open disk $B(0,d)$ for some number $d\geq 0$. Define $d(a,r)$ to be this number $d$. So any holomorphic function $f:\mathbb D\to r\mathbb D$ with $\left| f'(0)\right|=a$ must have range covering $B(0,d)$. Another characterization of $d(a,r)$ is: the least $d\geq 0$ such that for all $0<d-\varepsilon<d$ there is no holomorphic function $f:\mathbb D\to r\mathbb D-\{d-\varepsilon\}$ such that $\left| f'(0)\right|=a$.

We have $d(a,a)=a$ (Schwarz lemma) and $d(a,r)$ is increasing in $a$ and decreasing in $r$. Moreover $cd(a,r)=d(ca,cr)$ for $c>0$. Note that increase of $r$ leads to more freedom when constructing functions from $\mathbb D\to r\mathbb D$, and is possible to decrease $d(a,r)$ strictly. Consider

$$f:\mathbb D\to (e-1)\mathbb D$$
$$f(z)=e^z-1$$

We have $f'(0)=1$ and the largest disk centered at origin contained in $f(\mathbb D)$ has radius $1-e^{-1}$. So $d(1,e-1)\leq 1-e^{-1}<1$.

Some not so trivial results are:

1. When $r>a>0$, we have $d(a,r)<a$.

Proof by construction.

2. $d(a,r)>0$ if $a>0$.

Proof. Rouché's Theorem gives a (not very sharp) lower bound for $d(a,r)$. The rough idea is to give a $d>0$ such that $az-w$ and $f(z)-w$ are close enough on $\left| z\right|=z$ to apply Rouché's Theorem, for any $\left| w\right|<d$. Detail see [The images of all functions in a family contain a disk of fixed radius.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466133/the-images-of-all-functions-in-a-family-contain-a-disk-of-fixed-radius)

3. $\lim_{a\to r-}d(a,r)=r$

Proof. Montel and Hurwitz. Case $r=\infty$ is trivial, so let us assume $r<\infty$. If there is $0<b<r$ such that $d(a,r)<b$ for all $a<r$, then there is a sequence of functions $f_n:\mathbb D\to r\mathbb D-\{b\}$ with $\left|f_n'(0)\right|\to r$. By Montel's theorem, there is a subsequence that converges to some $f:\mathbb D\to r\mathbb D$ uniformly on compact sets. We have $\left|f'(0)\right|=r$, so $f$ is surjective by Schwarz lemma. Since $f$ is nonconstant, a corollary of Hurwitz theorem says $f$ should avoid $b$, a contradiction.

The main questions are

1. Is $D(a,r)$ closed or open?
2. Study and estimate $d(a,r)$. The best thing is, of course, to give a formula for $d(a,r)$. If this is not possible (which is probably the case), there are still many interesting questions to ask, for example:

Qualitatively:

Is $d(a,r)$ continuous in both variables? Is it differentiable, smooth, and even real analytic?

Is $d(a,r)$ strictly monotonic in each variable? Is it true that $d(a,\infty)=0$? (I guess this is true. If not, then we have a quite universal constant $d(1,\infty)$, which will make thing even more interesting.)

Quantitatively:

Can we construct more families of functions apart from the $e^z-1$ example, to give sharper upper bounds for $d(a,r)$? Can we refine the Rouché theorem proof to give sharper lower bounds for $d(a,r)$?